# Splitting a second order ODE into first order system in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cylindrical-coordinates

The equation is:

$$\frac{1}{1-r} \frac{d}{d r}\bigg((1-r)\frac{d \theta}{d r}\bigg) = -2\times 3.66\times (1-(1-r)^2)\,\theta$$

with boundary conditions: $\theta(r=0) = 0$ and $\frac{d \theta}{d r} = 0$ at $r=1$. To solve this I am employing shooting method and guessing for the value $\frac{d \theta}{d r} = 1.83$ at $r=0$.

I have come up with the following:
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d \theta}{dr} &= x \, ,\\
\frac{dx}{dr} &= \frac{x}{1-r} - 2\times 3.66\times\theta\, (2r-r^2) \, .
\end{aligned}
But solving this system of equations does not give me the value zero at $x(r=1)=0$ (ie.,  $\frac{d \theta}{d r} = 0$ at r=1).

How to split the above equation into two separate first-order ODE's to solve them?

Comment: Are you saying that the shooting algorithm fails to converge to $x(1)=0$? Does it get close?

Comment: It gives the value of $\infty$ at $x(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The DE can be analytically solved in terms of confluent hypergeometric functions (below).

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheFirstKind.html

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html

Of course, this is not the answer expected. But it makes clear the cause of the trouble encountered :

In fact, the initial conditions$\quad \theta_{(r=0)} = 0$ and $\left(\frac{d \theta}{d r}\right)_{(r=1)} = 0\quad$are not compatible to a non-nul solution $\theta(r)$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort to solve this analytically. I am actually looking for a numerical solution using shooting method. It need not only be shooting method, I am just interested in solving the ODE numerically.

Comment: You can't solve it numerically with the conditions $\quad \theta_{(r=0)} = 0$ and $\left(\frac{d \theta}{d r}\right)_{(r=1)} = 0\quad$ because with those conditions the unique finite solution is $\theta(r)=0$ for all values of $r$. That is the interest of the analytical sovlving to have proved it. You have to chose other conditions to obtain consistent numerical results.